# string c++ : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

Tags: c++, string

I'm reading from a file. First line of the file is just one number, second line is a sequence of up to 5 numbers separated by spaces. I have an if statement in a for loop that loops the length of the second line, but I get an out of range error on the line with my if statement. I'm so stuck, I've edited many times to no avail so I left it back where I started.

Let me know if you need any more code.

```
    //Reading from first line of file 
    prog1.seekg(0, prog1.beg);
    prog1 >>fteeth;
    prog1 >> fpattern;

    for(x=0; x < fteeth; x++){

        if ((fpattern.at(x) + 2 < 4) && (fpattern.at(x) + 2 > -1) && (fpattern.at(x) + 3 < 4) && (fpattern.at(x) -3 > -1)){

           farray[x] = 2;
            }
        else {
            farray[x] = 1;
        }
    }

    for(x=0; x < fteeth; x++){
        cout << farray[x] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try **stepping through** your code with a debugger, to see what the values of the variables are set to? Editing the code randomly is **never** a way to solve such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown by `at` when the index is out of range. So there is something wrong with the `x` used in the for-loop.

`prog1 >> fpattern;` will only read one "word", where "word" means any characters separated by whitespace. If you have five such words, or numbers, you will have to read five times.

Comment: so what im trying to do is access each number inside that second line (fpattern) because im using it in my for loop. i can see now that itll stop reading after the first number due to the space. could i use a getline to access those numbers in the way im trying to?